# Why we can not pass array of other datatype except string to Main

Tags: c#

```
static int Main(int[] args)
```

In the above example, I want to pass string of `int`.
   Another thing why we use only string of  array for command line argument.

Comment: Because the language spec says so?

Comment: Because that is how `Main` is defined? (Also title of the question is misleading, you can pass other array types, just not to `Main`)

Comment: Generally, `args` are provided to `Main()` from a command-line, which is a string that's split by whitespace (usually taking some extra care with quotations).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You should have written this as an answer, as its a better one than the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# language spec says that there are only two possible options for parameters: string[] and nothing.

> The Main method can be declared with or without a string[] parameter
>   that contains command-line arguments. When using Visual Studio to
>   create Windows Forms applications, you can add the parameter manually
>   or else use the Environment class to obtain the command-line
>   arguments. Parameters are read as zero-indexed command-line arguments.
>   Unlike C and C++, the name of the program is not treated as the first
>   command-line argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx